# Is the expression MyClass a = b + c a copy initialization?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, grammar

I know the expression like MyClass a = b is a copy initialization and it'll call the copy constructor.

What about MyClass a = b + c?

I have tried it. In visual studio 2015, it seems the expression is not a copy initialization nor a copy assignment.So what is it?

Below is the code I tested:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        cout << "default constructor has been called!" << endl;
    }
    MyClass(const MyClass& cls)
    {
        cout << "copy constructor has been called!" << endl;
    }
    MyClass operator+(const MyClass& cls) const
    {
        cout << "operator + has been called!" << endl;
        return MyClass();
    }
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& cls)
    {
        cout << "operator = has been called!" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass b, c;
    MyClass a = b + c;
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is

```
default constructor has been called!
default constructor has been called! 
operator + has been called!
default constructor has been called!
```

Comment: `MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& cls)` -- This function invokes undefined behavior since you failed to return a value.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I have corrected it.However I don't think it's a serious misleading in this question.

Comment: It's serious enough that it plays a part in how the program will work.  No return value, and anything can happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you experience is called return value optimization (see [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)).

The compiler optimizes code (to minimize objects created) and makes `a` actually be the local object declared and returned by your`+` operator. Then, there is no copy constructor used. This is what you observe here.

To nicely observe this, change your code to see object memory adresses:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass()
    {
        cout << "default constructor has been called for " << std::hex << this << endl;
    }
    MyClass(const MyClass& cls)
    {
        cout << "copy constructor has been called for " << std::hex << this << " (copied from " << &cls << ")" << endl;
    }
    MyClass operator+(const MyClass& cls) const
    {
        cout << "operator + has been called!" << endl;
        MyClass res;
        cout << "operator + returns temporary object " << std::hex << &res << endl;
        return res;
    }
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& cls)
    {
        cout << "operator = has been called!" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass b, c;
    MyClass a = b + c;
    cout << "a object is " << std::hex << &a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
default constructor has been called for 0x7ffd44b769fd
default constructor has been called for 0x7ffd44b769fe
operator + has been called!
default constructor has been called for 0x7ffd44b769ff
operator + returns temporary object 0x7ffd44b769ff
a object is 0x7ffd44b769ff
```

You see that temporary object created in `operator+` is the same as `a` (`0x7ffd44b769ff`), due to compiler optimization.

If you use g++, compile with `-fno-elide-constructors` to disable this compiler optimization. And the output is now:

```
default constructor has been called for 0x7ffd92847d1c
default constructor has been called for 0x7ffd92847d1d
operator + has been called!
default constructor has been called for 0x7ffd92847cff
operator + returns temporary object 0x7ffd92847cff
copy constructor has been called for 0x7ffd92847d1f (copied from 0x7ffd92847cff)
copy constructor has been called for 0x7ffd92847d1e (copied from 0x7ffd92847d1f)
a object is 0x7ffd92847d1e
```

You see that now `operator+` creates a local object (`0x7ffd92847cff`), which is later copied as a temporary object for return statement (copying `0x7ffd92847cff` to `0x7ffd92847d1f`), which is finally used to construct a by copy (copying `0x7ffd92847d1f` to `0x7ffd92847d1e`).

Answer (score 2):

The copy constructor [may be elided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) in such a case.

Answer (score 2):

From a c++ type perslective, there's no difference between

```
MyClass a = b + c;
```

and

```
MyClass a = MyClass();
```

since `operator+` returns an rvalue MyClass.   And since you just created exactly the object that you want `a` to be, it just makes that object directly into `a`.

This is described in the first example here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision